# How can i get all 3 grams from a line fetched from a text file in python?

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I fetched a line from a text file and the result it generates three grams of a line but at the end of line its output is two gram.
e.g input line is cswisceduwwt
**The output is**

```
csw
swi
wis
isc
sce
ced
edu
dup
upa
par
ara
rad
ady
dyn
yn
```

In the end of line, its generating 2 grams(2 characters) .The last gram is "yn" and i think its adding space. I don't need the "yn" How can I remove the last gram having 2 characters from each line?
The code is given below

```
def extract_n_grams(line):
        ngram = ngrams(line, 3)
        for item in ngram:
           result=item[0]+item[1]+item[2]
           print(result)

with open('C:/Users/Dania/Desktop/MS 2nd sem/preprocessed.txt') as corpus:
    for line in corpus:
        extract_n_grams(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was showing last two characters because it was including space as its last(3rd) character so i removed space in the the end of line by using this statement

```
for line in corpus:
        rem_line=line.rstrip('\n')  #####removes space at the end of line
        extract_n_grams(rem_line)
```